# Multitenant SAAS using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, multi-tenant, saas

I have been mainly focused on other frameworks like laravel and express.js. so i am new to django but have build several projects. I need to build a SAAS product. So which is the best approach.

1. Seperate database of each customers
2. Same db with tenant_id mapping

Or any other best solutions by SO gurus?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Django. But If you going to build a SAAS, one of the main things you need to think about from the beginning is scalability, which of course suggests the 2nd option. 1st one will be a nightmare when your SAAS is expanding.